# Batch - Why is 7zip command working improperly?

Tags: batch-file

**Here is my code:**

```
net use v: \\kimezgls-rez\arxiv_mppi                    
net use w: \\###.###.#.##\Protokoliem\KIMEZGLS-REZ_mppi 
cls
cd V:\
if not exist "V:\01_2016" mkdir "V:\01_2016"
pause
ECHO Folder is Created!
ECHO Moving Files...
MOVE "V:\??_01" "V:\01_2016"
ECHO Creating Backup!

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
for /d %%X in (01_2016) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\"
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

ECHO Please wait few seconds... 
ECHO Backup is Created!
ECHO Sending Backup to ###.###.#.##\Protokoliem\KIMEZGLS-REZ_mppi
MOVE "V:\01_2016.7z" "w:\"
pause
cls
pause
GOTO MENU
```

I am trying to make script, that will Create directory, name it 01_2016, and put all files, where name ends with _01 in it. Then Archive folder 01_2016 and send to Another Network folder.
Everything went well to the point, where script started to Archive folder 01_2016, but couldn't.

```
Scanning the drive:
WARNING: The system cannot find the file specified.
01_2016
0 files, 0 bytes
Creating archive: 01_2016.7z
Items to compress: 0
Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 32 bytes (1 KiB)
Scan WARNINGS for files and folders:
01_2016 : The system cannot find the file specified
----------------
Scan WARNINGS: 1
```

For some reason it saves empty .zip folder right on my Desktop. While anylyzing whole code, I came to conclusion, that this command is only thing that doesn't want to let me successfully run script.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try "cd /d V:\" (add /d).

Comment: God bless you @MichaelS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `CD V:\` is not enough. If you are on C:\ `CD V:\` won't move the scope to V:. To achieve this you have to add the `/d` switch to the `CD` command:

```
...
cd /d V:\
...
```